# What is the fastest procedure to remove duplicates from a big table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, bigdata

I have a table in MySQL (50 million rows) new data keep inserting periodically.

This table has following structure

```
CREATE TABLE values (
    id double NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    channel_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    val text NOT NULL,
    date_time datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY channel_date_index (channel_id,date_time)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Two rows must never have duplicate channel_id and date_time, but if such insert occurs it is important to keep the newest value.

Is there a procedure to check for duplicates realtime before the insert or should I keep inserting all data while doing periodic checks for duplicity in a different cycle.

Realtime speed is important here, because 100 inserts occur per second.

Comment: If your table is 50m rows and there's 100 inserts per second it's been in use for less than 6 days... if you create a unique index on `channel_id, date_time`, then perform an upsert as opposed to an insert when you add data to the table you should never have dupes.

Comment: As @Ben said, using primary keys and unique indexes is a *much* better way of doing this.  The table will outright reject any duplicates, so it would be impossible.  You would just need to spend your time on good secure error messages to users who try to enter duplicate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent *future* duplicates:

1. Change `KEY channel_date_index (channel_id,date_time)` to `UNIQUE (channel_id,date_time)`
2. Change the `INSERT` to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to change the timestamp when that pair exists.

To fix the existing table, you could do `ALTER IGNORE TABLE ... ADD UNIQUE(...)`.  However that would not give you the latest timestamps.

For minimum downtime (not maximum speed), use pt-online-schema-change.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334624/mysql-select-distinct-rows-not-columns-to-filter-post-for-duplicates